# Most Popular element (CPP)

Tags: c++

hey guys i'm trying to figure a way to get the most used element in a vector but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working and returning 1, any help would be appreciated.

from what i can see i think my thinking was correct but i guess not, thanks!

```
    std::sort(Track5Guess.begin(), Track5Guess.end());


    temp1 = Track5Guess.at(0);


    for (i = 1; i < Track5Guess.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if (track == false)
        {
            if (Track5Guess.at(i) == temp1)
            {
                counter1++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp2 = Track5Guess.at(i);
                track = true;
                i++;
            }
            if (track == true)
            {
                if (Track5Guess.at(i) == temp2)
                {
                    counter2++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (counter2 >= counter1)
                    {
                        temp1 = temp2;
                        track = false;
                        counter1 = counter2;
                        counter2 = 0;
                        temp2 = 0;
                    }

                    if (counter1 > counter2)
                    {
                        track = false;
                        counter2 = 0;
                        temp2 = 0;
                    }

                }
            }


        }
    }
    if (i == Track5Guess.size() - 1)
    {
        Num2Guess5 = temp1;
        temp1 = 0;
        counter1 = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Are using standard library classes and algorithms allowed? If not then use e.g. a [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) for the values, and then simply [count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/count) each "key".

Comment: @AndrewHebblethwaite, also, I would suggest to get a pen/pencil and a paper and try to solve the problem with pen and paper alone. If the solution is satisfactory, start coding. This will produce a good al;gorythm and eliminate many solution bugs.

Comment: Tip: if you can't think of better names than "counter1", "counter2", "temp1", and "temp2", it's usually a sign that you started writing code before figuring out a solution.